# Do in-atmosphere, above-water naval battles ever take place in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

Do above-water ship-to-ship battles ever take place in Star Wars?

We always see space-based "naval" battles and ground-based battles, but never traditional naval battles. I know that there is the Mon Cala *The Clone Wars* arc and the Kamino *The Clone Wars* arc but those only depict underwater battles and not above water battles.

I want any material (including non-canon materials like the Lego games) depicting above-water battles using ships and not solely submarines, though additional examples of underwater-only battles would also be nice.

Comment: This [Wookiepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Boat) article is the entry for boats and mentions warships as being specifically for "naval warfare".  Several links to stories that deal with them or mention them.

Comment: In Star Wars: Resistance the Colossus is based in water (at the beginning) but it is mostly attacked from the air.  Same for the Quarren ship in Episode 11 of The Mandalorian, traditional boat attacked from the air.

Comment: It's been like 20 years so I don't remember the specifics, so just posting as a comment, but there is a naval battle in one of the Rogue Squadron games.

Comment: I remembered boats in Rogue Squadron as well. Turns out they have Amphibion landing craft and AQ-5 Waveskimmer hovercraft in the Corellia and Mon Calamari levels respectively. However, it's always the player in a fighter shooting down at Imperial boats on the water, so it's a naval battle but not really ship-to-ship, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Legends

In *Dark Empire*, the Empire uses AQ-5 Waveskimmers on the surface of Mon Cala's ocean. These are boat-like craft that are used to defend the World Devastators attacking the planet.

[image: Image of an AQ-5 Waveskimmer skimming the surface of the ocean]
(source: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/AQ-5_Waveskimmer)

This may be stretching the definition, but in the 2D *Clone Wars* series, Republic Acclamator-class assault ships float on the water and act as battleships during the (earlier) Battle of Mon Cala, although the battle itself takes place underwater.

[image: Screencap of Clone Wars: Chapter 5, showing Republic ships on the ocean]
(source: Disney+)

Fleets of aquatic vehicles can also be built in *Galactic Battlegrounds*, and appear in some story missions:

[image: Image of in-game model for an Imperial ship]
(source: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Heavy_Missile_Destroyer_(Imperial))

In the original Marvel *Star Wars* comic series, the Dragon Lords of Drexel attack what appear to be wooden sailing ships while riding giant dragons:

[image: A seafaring ship is attacked by two dragons.]
(source: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Dragon_Lords)

Answer (score 3):

During the [Occupation of Man Cala](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Occupation_of_Mon_Cala), which takes place during the canon *Darth Vader: Dark Lord of the Sith* comic, battles take place on all battlefields: on land, underwater, and on the water. A specific example is when Admiral Ackbar leads an attack on an airbase using several aquatic vehicles, which fits the parameters of being in-atmosphere and above water.

[image: Mon Calamari aquatic vehicle]

Comment: Can you list or put images of some of the imperial boats used? Thats what I am most interested about .