# Do in-atmosphere naval battles ever take place in Warhammer 40k?

Tags: warhammer-40k

Inspired by [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/245597/do-in-atmosphere-above-water-naval-battles-ever-take-place-in-star-wars), do in-atmosphere naval battles ever happen in Warhammer 40k?  Unlike the example question, I am also interested in submarine battles as well.

Answer (score 6):

**YES**

In *Flesh and Iron* by Henry Zhou we have two Imperial Guard regiments specializing in wet-navy operations.  The 31st Riverine is a Vietnam-era Swiftboat style regiment (small boats with lots of troops for landing and rapid hit-and-run ops) along with a "Battleship" regiment whose name currently eludes me. But they both indicate they've fought "classic" naval operations in the past.

During the 3rd war for Armageddon the Orks utilized giant submarines to conduct amphibious operations against Imperial forces.

There is a small vignette from the 6th (?) Edition *Space Marines Codex* where Space Marine forces (using normal SM vehicles) fight Tau forces of a variety of types in undersea warfare.

The Titan Legions also conducted underwater combat ops during the Great Crusade/Heresy.  While it's not explicitly stated one can assume at least *some* of those fights would involve surface vessels or submarine equivalents.

Answer (score 5):

### Sort of

The classical navy definitely does exist in the Wh40k universe, although it rarely bothers to mention it. But the naval ships do exist:

- The Commissar Ciaphas Cain (**HERO OF THE IMPERIUM**) is at once stage assigned to a patrol boat to investigate the case of missing soldiers. In the "Traitor's hand" he takes part in an assault on a deep-sea mining platform.
- In "Blood Angels Omnibus" sergeant Rafen uses a submarine to sneak into the enemy base.
- Last, but definitely not least is the case of "Deff Skwadron", which tells WW II-style  plane fight between two warbosses, where you can see this beauty:

[image]
[image]

Yes, it's a (sea) ship. Quite Orky (but might need more dakka).

Comment: "MIght" need more dakka? Might? Ya stinkin' grot, it always needs more dakka!